# Adding a User Sign-in for Mobile App on a serverless backend on AWS

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

i am creating a mobile app for multiple platforms (iOS, Android, PWA (Web)) and have my backend build with the serverless framework on AWS Lambda, using API Gateway and DynamoDb.

My most recent goal is to add a user login using AWS Cognito, enabling my users to either login using their email and password, or a facebook login. I read multiple threads, tutorials and the official AWS Documentation but am super confused because of the mass of different information.

I want to integrate authorized API Endpoints which can only be called when the user is logged in.

Therefore my first question is:

**1) Should i rather use AWS Cognito User Pools or AWS Cognito Identity Pools?**

I also read that for user pools you can solely use the hosted UI for login, which is not a possibility for my app. I want to style my own login page.

As i could not find any sample code for the client side integration, i went with identity Pools for now, and created an endpoint in my serverless.yml which is specified the following:

```
functions:
  xxx-auth:
    handler: endpoints/xxx-auth.execute
    events:
      - http: 
          path: xxx-auth
          method: put
          cors: true
          integration: lambda
          authorizer: aws_iam
```

So my second question is:

**2) How do i properly integrate the authorization for my Cognito Identity Pool or User Pool?**

From another Thread i read that there is the possibility to generate an SDK for the API one created on API Gateway, which handles the signature procedures of the request for you. As i tried to do so in my iOS application, i first log the user in using the following code:

```
let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .EUCentral1 ,
                                                            identityPoolId:"eu-central-1:XXXXXXXX" ,
                                                            identityProviderManager: CustomIdentityProvider(tokens: ["graph.facebook.com": FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString]))
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .EUCentral1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
```

and then use the following created code to submit the PUT request:

```
public func XXXPut() -> AWSTask<AnyObject> {
    let headerParameters = [
               "Content-Type": "application/json",
               "Accept": "application/json",

            ]

    let queryParameters:[String:Any] = [:]

    let pathParameters:[String:Any] = [:]

    return self.invokeHTTPRequest("PUT", urlString: "/XXX", pathParameters: pathParameters, queryParameters: queryParameters, headerParameters: headerParameters, body: nil, responseClass: nil)
}
```

But i cannot see any code that signs the HTTP request. Therefore the third question is:

**3) How do i create the SDK that properly sends the signed HTTP request to my API Gateway backend?**

I also tried the same for Cognito User Pools, using a simple "Authorization" header, but could not figure out a way to obtain the respective Authorization token on the iOS application without using any kind of hosted UI.

It would be very kind if someone could explain this jungle to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by myself:

1) It depends. I am now using a combination of both for the following reason:
For a Facebook Login, we are using a Cognito Identity Pool, as the Cognito UserPool does not support a Facebook Login outside of the hosted UI. For Email signup and login we use a UserPool inside the Cognito Identity Pool.

2) The code snippet i posted was correct.

3) The code snippet was also correct. My mistake was that i did not correctly display and inspect the reply of my API and therefore thought the request was not authorized, but it was.